# Can't connect to Bluemix using MQTTlens or MQTThelper

Tags: ibm-cloud, mqtt, watson-iot

I have successfully sent messages using mosquitto_pub command to connect device in Bluemix, but when I am doing the same with MQTTlens or MQTThelper I can't connect. I have configured it as on tutorials http://heidloff.net/article/useful-mqtt-tools-ibm-watson-iot-bluemix?cm_mc_uid=27677244132415055778021&cm_mc_sid_50200000=1505944109

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

@emir I was able to connect and publish messages with MQTTLens over insercure connection (1883)

[image]

[image]

Also, MQTTHelper worked for me just fine:

[image]

Maybe you can try again, it could be that there where some network issues that could cause the timeout.